# Can a webjob run on schedular even when the host website is stopped?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

My Scenario is very simple

1. A website running in azure which is the host of the webjob (the webjob will run under the context of this website).
2. A webjob, which is a console based application, scheduled to run every 5 minutes. Printing just a log message using COnsole.Writeline

Now, if i stop the website and go and check the execution logs of the webjob, it still gets executed every 5 minutes.

So when we say webjob runs in the same context of the website, what it actually means?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "context" here means that the WebSite and WebJob run in the same environment, with access to the same files. For example, you can prepare data for the WebSite in the WebJob. Conversely, you can save data in the WebSite scripts to be later batch-processed by the WebJob. You can also manage WebJobs the same way as the WebSite, they are all accessible using the same FTP(S) account.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [kudu documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-architecture), it says :

> **Process model**
>
> The Kudu service site runs in the same sandbox as the site. By default, it runs in the different process as the site.
>
> The only thing that really 'connects' the Kudu site to the real site is the file system, and that works regardless of what process or machine they each run on.

So your webjob run under the same environment but used a different process. It shares settings, files but if your website is turn off your web jo will continue on running.